# Score probability groups with Random Forest in R

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, random-forest, probability

I would like to use RF in order to get a score probability of a binary outcome, in order to know groups with higher probability of buy something. Like this:

```
fit<-randomForest(formula = buy ~.  , data = pract,importance = TRUE ,ntree =1000) 


pract$PREDICTION <- as.vector(predict(fit,type='prob',newdata=pract)[,2])

test$PREDICTION <- as.vector(predict(fit,type='prob',newdata=test)[,2])
```

First Question, When I perfom auc of the pract$PREDICTION I get 1! It is because overfiting? Should I use out of bag instead of pract, like this?:

```
pract$PREDICTION <- as.vector(predict(fit,type='prob')[,2])
```

Second Question:

With test$PREDICTION I want to make groups ordered by the score prob, like this:

```
test$score[test$PREDICTION >= 0 & test$PREDICTION <=0.3] <-  1
    test$score[test$PREDICTION > 0.3 & test$PREDICTION <=0.6] <- 2
...
test$score[test$PREDICTION > 0.9 & test$PREDICTION <=1.0] <- 10
```

How can I measure how good my model is? by doing the same segmentation group in the pract$PREDICTION and then comparing how right and how wrong both tests are in each group ? This make any sense?

Comment: What do the buy vs non-buy probabilities look like?  Random forests typically doesn't overfit that much, so I would look more into the forest and your data to figure out what is going on.  For your second question, AUC is a solid measure for this, as is measuring the lift in each segmentation group.